# Visual Studio 2013 coexisting Ankh SVN and Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn

I have two project. The older project (let call it A) is located in subversion repository and newer project B is located in Git repository.

I work with both of these projects in Visual Studio 2013. I have read that the selection of Source control provider shlould be bind with solution, but it does not work for me.

I open sln A and I set up source control provider to AnkhSVN.
I open pending changes from menu and it just works.
I close solution A.

I open sln B.
I open team explorer connected to Git provider and I work with it. It works fine.
I close sln B.

I open solution A and I expect the Anhk provider to be set up, **but it is not**. The source control provider setting is overriden. I have to go every time to Tool -> Option -> Source Control -> Plugin Selection and change the provider to AnkhSVN. It is very annoying.

How do you use it? Is there any solution?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, largely in the other direction. To get GIT source provision to work for my Visual Studio Online GIT solution I have to completely uninstall AnkhSVN. I was blaming Ankh, but maybe it's a VS problem.

Answer (score 2):

After almost one year dealing with this issue I have two workarounds:

1. Set [ankhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) as Visual Studio Source Control provider and use git as external tool.
2. Wrap your SVN repositories with Microsoft Git Provider ([git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)) and use only git as the Visual Studio Source Control provider.

I prefer option 2.

Answer (score -1):

To make sure the correct source control provide is used when opening the solution, you have to connect the solution to source control. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka7d2dw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on how to do this.

Comment: This article refers only to Visual Studio 2005 and 2008. There is no such menu in Visual Studio 2013.